# Proper Trigonometry For Rotating A Point Around The Origin

Tags: c#, c++, geometry, trigonometry

Do either of the below approaches use the correct mathematics for rotating a point?  If so, which one is correct?

```
POINT rotate_point(float cx,float cy,float angle,POINT p)
{
  float s = sin(angle);
  float c = cos(angle);

  // translate point back to origin:
  p.x -= cx;
  p.y -= cy;

  // Which One Is Correct:
  // This?
  float xnew = p.x * c - p.y * s;
  float ynew = p.x * s + p.y * c;
  // Or This?
  float xnew = p.x * c + p.y * s;
  float ynew = -p.x * s + p.y * c;

  // translate point back:
  p.x = xnew + cx;
  p.y = ynew + cy;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. What are cx and cy? Also, you have declared your function of type POINT, but it doesn't return a POINT, or indeed anything.

Comment: @Brian Hooper: +1 for pointing out the benefits of meaningful variable names ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on how you define `angle`. If it is measured counterclockwise (which is the mathematical convention) then the correct rotation is your first one:

```
// This?
float xnew = p.x * c - p.y * s;
float ynew = p.x * s + p.y * c;
```

But if it is measured clockwise, then the second is correct:

```
// Or This?
float xnew = p.x * c + p.y * s;
float ynew = -p.x * s + p.y * c;
```

Answer (score 33):

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29#Matrix_algebra)

To carry out a rotation using matrices the point (x, y) to be rotated is written as a vector, then multiplied by a matrix calculated from the angle, θ, like so:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/0/e/d/0ed0d28652a45d730d096a56e2d0d0a3.png]

where (x′, y′) are the co-ordinates of the point after rotation, and the formulae for x′ and y′ can be seen to be

[image]

Comment: Don't forget, that if you're working in a typical screen coordinate space that your y axis will be inverted from the mathematical standard (down is +y, up is -y) and you'll need to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is extracted from my own vector library..

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Returns clockwise-rotated vector, using given angle and centered at vector
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CVector2D   CVector2D::RotateVector(float fThetaRadian, const CVector2D& vector) const
{
    // Basically still similar operation with rotation on origin
    // except we treat given rotation center (vector) as our origin now
    float fNewX = this->X - vector.X;
    float fNewY = this->Y - vector.Y;

    CVector2D vectorRes(    cosf(fThetaRadian)* fNewX - sinf(fThetaRadian)* fNewY,
                            sinf(fThetaRadian)* fNewX + cosf(fThetaRadian)* fNewY);
    vectorRes += vector;
    return vectorRes;
}
```

Comment: You could save the `cosf` and `sinf` results to variables to use half as many trig function calls. :)